# How comes the syntax changes for dicts (since apparently keys must be strings) when using **kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this piece of code for example, keys seem to be keywords using the '=' sign instead of the usual dict syntax {"key":"value"} as in the second piece of code

```
    def myfunc(**kwargs):
        if "fruits" in kwargs:
            print(f"My fruit of choice is {kwargs['fruits']}")
        else:
            print("I did not find any fruit here")
    myfunc(fruits = "apple", veggies = "cabbage")



    my_dict = {"fruits":"apple", "veggies":"cabbages"}
    my_dict["fruits"]
```

Comment: That's just how keyword arguments work: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Answer (score 1):

Keyword arguments predate the ability to specify *arbitrary* keyword arguments. In the beginning, there were only positional parameters:

```
def foo(a, b):
    ...
```

and you could only specify positional arguments:

```
foo(3, 5)
```

Next came keyword arguments: you could specify the parameters by name at call time, both for readability and to relax the requirement to provide arguments in the order they were defined:

```
foo(a=3, b=5)
foo(b=5, a=3)  # Identical to the above
```

Later, the ability to add keyword arguments that weren't predefined as parameters was added. These are exposed inside the function as a `dict`, created at call time, and assigned to the parameter prefixed with `**`:

```
def foo(a, b, **kwargs):
    ...

foo(a=3, b=5, c=9)  # kwargs['c'] will have the value 9.
```

No change was made to the *calling* syntax; as far as the caller is concerned, the fact that a `dict` is used to access the value of `c` is an implementation detail, and one that is not exposed outside the function.

A separate, but related, use of `**` is to unpack a `dict` as a sequence of keyword arguments:

```
foo(**{'a': 3, 'b': 5})  # Equivalent to foo(a=3, b=5)
```